Talend job failing with coummunication error while closing mysql connection
I have a talend job which is failing with below error while closing the connection. Talend jobs are scheduled using airflow. The error gets resolved if I re-run the job from airflow.  This is not affecting the data loading process.
Origin: tMysqlClose_1
Message: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException:Communications link failure during rollback(). Transaction resolution unknown.

I am using post job in talend and then closing the connection. Please see below.

Can i close the connection immediately after the data loading instead of using post job in talend?
